# How to manage json in html template sent through SSE flask

Tags: python, flask, server-sent-events

I need to push json to my HTML template endlessly. On html template I want to manage this json and insert data from it to html page.
Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    def event_stream():
        counter = 0
        while True:
            yield "data: {}\n\n".format({"a": "1", "b": "2"})
            time.sleep(10)
    return Response(event_stream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

and html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var eventSource = new EventSource("/stream");
            eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
            alert(e.data);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For now **alert** does not work. And my json is displayed on HTML page even if to remove js script from html. How can I manipulate with json in my html?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a json to your AJAX call and use it from "success".

Flask:

```
@app.route('/my_route',methods=['GET','POST'])
def my_function():
    request_json=request.get_json()
    html_string= some_processing(request_json)
    return jsonify(result=html_string)
```

AJAX:

```
success : function(data){ $('#id-where_html_goes').html(data.result); },
```

Comment: Hi, I need to use 'server-sent-events' and all json manipulation only within sse